# Check if url exists JAVA

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to check if the url entered by the user actually exists. 
Below is what I have tried.

```
public static Boolean checkURLExists(String urlName) 
{
    Boolean urlCheck=false;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlName);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
        String responseMessage = huc.getResponseMessage();
        char a=String.valueOf(Math.abs((long)huc.getResponseCode())).charAt(0);
        if ((a == '2' || a == '3')&& (responseMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")||responseMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("found")||responseMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("redirect"))) {
            System.out.println("GOOD "+responseCode+" - "+a);
            urlCheck=true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("BAD "+responseCode+" - "+a);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return urlCheck;
}
```

The issue with the above code is that it returns http://www.gmail.com or http://www.yahoo.co.in etc. as invalid URLs with response code 301 & response message "Moved permanently" but they actually redirects to other url, Is there any way to detect that the url when entered in browser will open a page?

Thank you.

Comment: You could follow that redirect (might be a 302 in other cases) or just trust them that the redirect url is correct. Why do you check the message as well as the first character of the status code instead of just the _entire_ status code? That's all you'd need.

Comment: You should use `HEAD` rather than `GET` for this purpose. It retrieves only the headers of the page, which is faster and enough to check if the page is available.

Comment: Just a digression: `char a=String.valueOf(Math.abs((long)huc.getResponseCode())).charAt(0);
        if ((a == '2' || a == '3')` What the hell is going on here ?? ;) simple `code>=200 && code <400` would be more then sufficient

Comment: `char a=String.valueOf(Math.abs((long)huc.getResponseCode())).charAt(0)` is ridiculous. The response code won't be negative, and you don't need to get it as a character in the first placve. You should just get it as an integer and make sure it is < 299 or whatever your constraints are. Implement, don't obfuscate.

Comment: Use **HEAD** method instead of **GET**.
Good explanation [here](https://ochronus.com/http-head-request-good-uses/)

Comment: Already tried that.. But that's not solving the problem

Comment: @Antoniossss Oh, that's really vague, Thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: @Thomas the invalid URL's like www.dsfdsoijmdfskl.com gives 301 response code same as www.yahoo.com but with different messages "Moved Permanently" in former case and "Redirect" in later case which helps in distinguishing.

Comment: @Thomas Or is there any way to do the same using ajax since the above code gives error for mail.google.com too :(

Comment: Well, I'd not rely on the messages. If you don't trust the status code 301 you shouldn't trust the message either. Only option then: follow the redirect and check again (keep an eye on multiple redirects though, I'd probably just mark the url as invalid if you get a 301 or 302 from the redirect as well).

Comment: Additionally, keep in mind that urls can change, i.e. one that is valid today might not exist anymore tomorrow. Since I guess you want to store the user input in some way you'd have to think about that as well.

Comment: @Thomas Definitely your point is valid regarding the change of current URLs in future. Talking about marking 301 or 302 to invalid would reject the URLs like google.com or yahoo.com which returns the 3xx codes.
Could you please elaborate how to follow the redirect since I don't know how to do that in java as I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the normal behavior of a web browser when  it sees a 301 response is to follow the redirect.  But you seem to have told your test code NOT to do that.  If you want your code to behave (more) like a browser would, change this

```
  HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

to this

```
  HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

Comment: Thank you.. I know it's too late but I totally forgot to accept the answer.